# Python - summing numbers that is the same

Tags: python, list, duplicates

```
a = [2,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7]
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

I want to sum the numbers in 'b' that in 'a' are the same and remove the duplicated numbers in 'a', so the output should look like:

```
a = [2,3,4,5,6,7]
b = [6,4,5,13,27,23]
```

Comment: So what happened on items of `b`?

Comment: summing b that are duplicated in a

Comment: So where did the 4 came from?

Comment: I see it. The numbers are paired.

Comment: can you explain that how you get `b = [6,4,5,13,27,23]` exactly? i think 6 is `2+2+2` but what about the rest?

Comment: list a and list b are linked. 6 is 1+2+3, 4 and 5 was in the list, 13 is 6+7 etc

Comment: Solved it, finally understood what it meant.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension, zipping the two lists together:

```
sums = [sum(y for x, y in zip(a, b) if x == i) for i in [j[0] for j in groupby(a)]]
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot Padraic. I'll fix it, just give me a moment.

Comment: If you want to maintain order use  OrderedDict.fromkeys

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Sorry for taking a while, working on a history project for school. Decided to use groupby.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `izip_longest` and `collections.defaultdict` this is a fast and comprehensive way for solve this problem as it works if the length of `a` and `b` was not the same :

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> d=defaultdict(int)

>>> for i,j in izip_longest(a,b):
...   d[i]+=j
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {2: 6, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 13, 6: 27, 7: 23})
>>> d.values()
[6, 4, 5, 13, 27, 23]
```

But as Padraic Cunningham  noted dicts are not ordered although in this case the answer is true!!

as an alternative answer but less efficient you can use `itertools.groupby` :

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest,groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> [sum([i[1] for i in g]) for _,g in groupby(izip_longest(a,b),key=itemgetter(0))]
[6, 4, 5, 13, 27, 23]
```

Comment: dicts don't have order

Comment: @PadraicCunningham mmm, yes its a problem but why here its exactly ordered?

Comment: because the output is in order of how the elements occur in list a, that is not guaranteed using a normal dict or sets

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes you are right i added this point to answer! thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 0):

`OrderedDict.fromkeys` will create a set of the elements in `a` and keep order:

```
a = [2,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7]
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import islice

od = OrderedDict.fromkeys(a,0,)

for ele in a:
    od[ele] += 1

it = iter(b)
sums = [sum(islice(it,v)) for v in od.values()]

print(list(od))
print(sums)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[6, 4, 5, 13, 27, 23]
```

If you use a set you will have no guaranteed order, it is also unclear if you have elements that repeat later in your list `a` and what exactly happens if that is the case.

To work with later repeating elements:

```
a = [2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,13]

from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import islice, count

it = iter(a)
seq = 1
prev = next(it)
cn = count()
od = OrderedDict()
for ele in it:
    if ele == prev:
        seq += 1
    else:
        od[next(cn)] = seq
        seq = 1
    prev = ele
if prev == ele:
    seq += 1
    od[next(cn)] = seq


st_a = OrderedDict.fromkeys(a)

it = iter(b)

sums = [sum(islice(it, v)) for v in od.values()]
print(list(st_a))
print(sums)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[6, 4, 5, 13, 17, 10, 11, 25]
```